# Is it incorrect to re-assign to a pointer which contains an autoreleased object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, autorelease, alloc

What is the result of the following?

```
NSString *myStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World."] autorelease];
myStr = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello Again."];
```

Does `myStr` get correctly released or does this crash, since we would call `autorelease` on `myStr` which is now set to a string that is already autoreleased?

Comment: Just use ARC, it will fix all of these problems. Backwards compatibility is much more of a hassle than just using what apple recommends (ARC).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Not entirely true in all cases.  For instance some third party libraries do not support ARC.  Memory management is still a necessary concept in iOS.

Comment: @MikeD just compile the libraries with -fno-objc-arc. ARC is still the best way to go.

Comment: Our app is pretty huge and I think transitioning to ARC would take a long time.  According to static analyzer, we currently have 500+ memory issues that I'm working on fixing :<

Comment: Interesting question (although fairly easy to test out).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code example works the way you would expect.  `autorelease` can't somehow change what object it refers to after you send the message.  The `@"Hello World."` and `@"Hello Again."` objects are different objects, even though your example uses the same pointer variable to refer to them.

Comment: So technically the autorelease will get sent to "Hello World.", right?

Comment: "get sent to"?  It already *has* been sent.  It's not like the message gets queued up to get sent later or something.

Comment: I mean, when the autorelease pool starts, it will call release on "Hello World."?

Comment: Yes, I just want to make sure release isn't being sent twice and I don't think it is.  Thanks for your help.